# How to do `has_one: model, through: join_model` in JSONAPI::Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonapi-resources

What's the preferred way to do `has_one :model, through: join_model` in a model resource? Usually `JSONAPI::Resource` expects `model_id` column on the table/model who owns the association. That does not exist if a join table/model is used.

Comment: was my answer able to help you?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. But my question was about `has_one` not `has_many`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I saw 'has' and 'through' and my mind immediately went to `has_many`. So far, I've only needed `has_many` relationships when I've been using `JSONAPI::Resource`. However, since the relationship structure is essentially the same for a `has_one`, I'd imagine the relationship declaration in the resource would just be `has_one` (similar to my answer below), since that's the way it works for `has_many`.

Comment: have you had a chance yet to see if using `has_one <model name>` works as you need it to in your resource?

Comment: I'm not working on the project now that's why I'm not reacting early to your comments. Forgive me.

Comment: not a problem. Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just mention the `has_many` relationship, with no need to mention the `through` association.

So if you had this model structure:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classrooms
  has_many :students, through: :classrooms
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classrooms
  has_many :teachers, through: :classrooms
end

class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :student
end
```

In your `Teacher` resource, all you'd need is `has_many :students`.

And likewise, in your `Student` resource, you'd need `has_many :teachers`.